# After installing the spring-security-core grails plugin, how do you get IDEA to know about the jar files?

Tags: grails, plugins, jar, intellij-idea, installation

I have installed spring-security-core in a grails project, but for some reason, IDEA didn't automatically pick up the jar files. I can deploy the app and run tests using the grails command line just fine... but IDEA still puts squiggly lines. Is there a way I can get IDEA to automatically pick up jars after I install plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% what the real source of this problem is. To my knowledge, IntelliJ parses the BuildConfig.groovy inside plugins to configure dependencies. It seems, that it does *not* pickup the autogenerated dependencies.groovy. The packaged spring-security-core plugin just contains a dependencies.groovy and no BuildConfig.groovy.

I've added the following snippet to my app's BuildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.core:3.0.2.RELEASE') {
        excludes 'com.springsource.org.aopalliance',
                'com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging',
                'org.springframework.beans',
                'org.springframework.context',
                'org.springframework.core'
    }

    compile('org.springframework.security:org.springframework.security.web:3.0.2.RELEASE') {
        excludes 'com.springsource.javax.servlet',
                'com.springsource.org.aopalliance',
                'com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging',
                'org.springframework.aop',
                'org.springframework.beans',
                'org.springframework.context',
                'org.springframework.core',
                'org.springframework.web'
    }
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.5'
}
```

With this, IntelliJ "knows" about the Spring Security jars.

Comment: This solution is great. It affects everyone on the project at the same time. You rock!

Comment: I have not tried, but IntelliJ might have fixed this in their latest EAP.

Comment: Just a follow up on this: in IntelliJ 9.0.3 the above hack is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case (9.0.2) was that the grailsPlugins did not have grails library on it's classpath. So the compile dependencies would not work, and your fix fabien is a bit to verbose :-)

IDEA normally has a great auto error fix (alt + enter) and it works in this case to. It will ask you to "Add grails user library to classpath". Works like a charm but should offcourse not be necessary

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Project Structure Window
2. in Project Settings choose Modules
3. then choose the plugin module. It should be named "myproject-grailsPlugin"
4. then select the tab dependencies
5. Inside the dependent modules, select Grails User Library (if it does not exist, create it with Add -> Global Library)
6. EDIT this library and inside the Configure Module Library dialog, choose "Attach JAR directories"
7. Select the lib directory of the spring-security-code plugin. O windows it should be located ate : C:\Users\myuser.grails\1.3.1\projects\myproject\plugins\spring-security-core-0.3.1\lib

That's it !

Comment: spring-security-core-0.3.1 don't have lib/ dir.

Answer (score 0):

why not just right click on your project root directory and click 'synchronize grails dependencies'...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like intellij 9.0.3 does not correctly pick up dependencies from plugins when you change the plugin directory to something other other than default one in BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.project.plugins.dir = "./plugins"  //breaks plug-ins in intellij
```

Class not found errors started appearing after changing the plugin directory.  I added the dependencies from the modules (namely spring-security-core and springcache) and now intellij adds the jar dependencies to 'Grails user library' and I can compile my app.  Using the command line never had any issue.

Here's what I added to BuildConfig for springcache.

```
dependencies {   
//for spring-security-core
```

// for springcache
    compile("net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-web:2.0.0") {
            excludes "ehcache-core" // ehcache-core is provided by Grails
        }

}